# My tsqlt unit test for a stored procedure is not included in the code coverage?

Tags: t-sql, tsqlt

In my tsqlt unit test for a stored procedure.  I fake my tables, Copy data into them from my AutotestDB.  Then run the SP.  Load the results into my actuals.  Also insert into my expected, hardcoded values. Then I AssertEqualsTable and the unit test passes. However, in the code coverage report, the stored procedure that i executed does not appear.  This is strange because on my other unit tests the executed stored procedure appears.

Any ideas as to why this is happening?

Comment: What are you using to measure code coverage?

Comment: @EdElliott its just the standard tsqlt code coverage tab.  is it configurable somewhere?